# What is the purpose of byteBuffer.get() & 0xFF?

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I found this method:

```
private static int getInt16(ByteBuffer input) {
    return ((input.get() & 0xFF) << 8) | (input.get() & 0xFF);
}
```

What is the purpose of `input.get() & 0xFF`? Isn't it the same as `input.get()`?

Comment: you get two digits from input, take only first byte and concatenate to an two byte value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pulling bytes (which are 8 bits in size) from `input` and combining them into `Int16`s, which is what the method returns.  The `& 0xFF` is insuring that the bytes haven't been sign-extended (which may be unnecessary, but can't hurt).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking as if `input.get()` returns unsigned byte.. Java uses singed bytes.  A little explanation [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gencoreoperative/index/java-development/java-unsigned-bytes).